# Newbie on R and newbie to programmation - fusion all values of a vector into one some value

Tags: r

It might be a dumb question but I'm very new to programming and I'm currently working with R
I want to transform a vector `A = "AT" "GCT" "TCA"` into `A ="ATGCTTCA"`.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(A, collapse="")
#[1] "ATGCTTCA"
```

---

Or with `paste` from `base R`

```
paste(A, collapse="")
#[1] "ATGCTTCA"
```

#### data

```
A <- c("AT", "GCT", "TCA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `paste0()` over your vector:

```
#Data
A = c("AT","GCT","TCA") 
#Collapse
Anew <- paste0(A,collapse = '')
```

Output:

```
[1] "ATGCTTCA"
```